# Spring boot Hibernate Schema Multitenancy Dynamic Tenant

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am trying to set-up schema multitenancy in my webapp using Hibernate.
I've followed some tutorials and i've come to:
implement my own *MultiTenantConnectionProvider* 
implement my own *CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver* 
implement *TenantContext*
change *HibernateConfig*

I have a default **public** schema and some schemas per tenant (the public schema has a table with all the tenants). 
In short, what i am trying to do now is:

1. recive tenantId via API,
2. query the public.tenants table and control if tenant is enabled
3. if tenant is enabled, query a certain table from his schema

Right now i am stuck at changing from public to tenant schema.

What worked for now is to modify the method MultiTenantConnectionProvider.getConnection, in order to set the tenant before executing the query, then get the tenant directly from the context.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71cJk.png)

In that case i am not using the tenantIdentifier parameter but i try to get the tenant directly from the context.
It works only if i don't query the public schema first but just set tenant and execute the query on the tenant schema.

If i execute a query on the public schema first then change the tenant, my solution doesn't work anymore, because spring uses the same connection for both queries.

Do you have any advices?

Comment: Have you found this: https://medium.com/swlh/multi-tenancy-implementation-using-spring-boot-hibernate-6a8e3ecb251a

Comment: Yes, I followed it for some parts, but my case is different, i want to change tenant in the same request call, so a Interceptor won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone intrested I found a solution. The problem is documented in [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9766) ticket from 2015. You can't change the tenant in the same session. 
The workaround I found is to create a new thread, set your tenant there and then execute your CRUD service. 
If you don't want to do that, I found another way to do it:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.setSchema(schemaName);
            operationService.create(newOperation);
        }
    });
```

This way you use the same session, so it's all managed by Hibernate, you just change the schema manually.